# Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getListAdapter() from the type ListActivity

Tags: java, android, listadapter

```
public class AdapterHelp extends ListActivity{

public static ListAdapter returnAdapter(){
    ListAdapter adapter = (ListAdapter) getListAdapter();
    return adapter;
}
}
```

Hi,I'm having problem wth this simple class.
It shows me an error.
**Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getListAdapter() from the type ListActivity**

So can anyone please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: You need to learn what the `static` keyword means.

Comment: I'm using static here because I'm using this method in another class.

Comment: @VaibhavDevpura: This is bad design, I would suggest re-evaluate.

Comment: You should NOT be creating `public` methods in any type of `Activity` in order to use them from other application components. That is not how the Android `Activity` class is meant to be used.

Comment: @Nambari this is not my whole design.this is just a small example that will make you understand easily.

Comment: @VaibhavDevpura: Understood, as Squonk commented, this won't work with android.

Comment: You can't call a non static member/method from a static method. Thats the reason for your error msg.

Comment: yeah got it.But Can anyone tell me Is there any other way that I won't get such errors as I'm beginner in Android.

Comment: You get an error because what you want to do makes no sense (which makes it impossible). You have to change what you want to do, not try to get rid of the error by using some fairy dust. We can't help you, unless you understand it. Probably you will need to change the method to non-static and pass an instance of the activity to the object that needs it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For practical purposes, static methods and variables don't need an instance of the class for them to be called or used, while any other method requires an instance of the class to be used, this means that you can't call non-static methods from static methods, given that if you do so, no one can guarantee that there is going to be an instance of the class for the required method to work.

In the other hand if you create an instance of the class that have the getListAdapter() method inside your static method, you will be able to call it. For more information about static methods and variables you can check [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_variable)